# Visualisation with VTK and Python causing a semi-regular pattern

Tags: python, visualization, vtk

Hi and thank you in advance for your time.

I am currently creating a software package which is going to allow the user to visualise imported data. The data I am currently using is a .txt file with dimensions 120 columns by 24320 rows. Which I am importing and converting to a 3D grid with dimensions 120x128x190. I am then comparing this data to a threshold value and assigning a value of 1 to any cells which have a value greater than the threshold. This is all fine and I even manually checked the data by saving it and cross checking it with the txt file and it was correct, however I cannot get the visualisation to work correctly and instead of outputting a heart shape it gives a very regular grid like pattern (see http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/4944/vtk.png). I am really tearing my hair out trying to get this to work so any help at all would be very much appreciated. The code I am currently using is:

```
import vtk
from vtk.util import vtkImageImportFromArray
from numpy import *

#intensity threshold 900000

# import the data
# read files
intensityI=[]

print("Reading files...")

in_file = open("intensity.txt", "rt")
for line in in_file.readlines():
    intensityI.append([])
    for i in line.split():
        intensityI[-1].append(float(i))
in_file.close()

print("...done")

#set parameters specific to data
nx = 119
ny = 127
nz = 189
sizex=nx+1
sizey=ny+1
sizez=nz+1
threshold = 900000

#convert to array
I = zeros((sizez, sizex, sizey))
It = zeros((sizez, sizex, sizey), dtype=uint8)

print("converting to 3D array...")
z=0
while z<sizez:
    x=0
    while x<sizex:
        y=0
        while y<sizey:
            I[z][x][y] = int(intensityI[(z*128)+y][x])
            #print(I[z][x][y])
            #print(int(intensityI[(z*128)+y][x]))
            if I[z][x][y] > threshold:
                It[z][x][y] = 1
            y += 1
        x += 1
    z += 1

print("...done")

print("converting to string...")

# I now contains raw intensity information
# It contains thesholded intensity

dataImporter = vtk.vtkImageImport()
data_string = It.tostring()
dataImporter.CopyImportVoidPointer(data_string, len(data_string))
dataImporter.SetDataScalarTypeToUnsignedChar()
dataImporter.SetNumberOfScalarComponents(1)
dataImporter.SetDataExtent(0, nz, 0, ny, 0, nx)
dataImporter.SetWholeExtent(0, nz, 0, ny, 0, nx)

print("...done")
print("drawing...")

alphaChannelFunc = vtk.vtkPiecewiseFunction()
alphaChannelFunc.AddPoint(1, 0.05)
alphaChannelFunc.AddPoint(0, 0.0)

colorFunc = vtk.vtkColorTransferFunction()
colorFunc.AddRGBPoint(1, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
#colorFunc.AddRGBPoint(0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

volumeProperty = vtk.vtkVolumeProperty()
volumeProperty.SetColor(colorFunc)
volumeProperty.SetScalarOpacity(alphaChannelFunc)

compositeFunction = vtk.vtkVolumeRayCastCompositeFunction()
volumeMapper = vtk.vtkVolumeRayCastMapper()
volumeMapper.SetVolumeRayCastFunction(compositeFunction)
volumeMapper.SetInputConnection(dataImporter.GetOutputPort())

volume = vtk.vtkVolume()
volume.SetMapper(volumeMapper)
volume.SetProperty(volumeProperty)

renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renderWin.AddRenderer(renderer)
renderInteractor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
renderInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWin)

renderer.AddVolume(volume)
renderer.SetBackground(0,0,0)
renderWin.SetSize(400, 400)

def exitCheck(obj, event):
    if obj.GetEventPending() != 0:
        obj.SetAbortRender(1)

renderWin.AddObserver("AbortCheckEvent", exitCheck)

renderInteractor.Initialize()
renderWin.Render()
renderInteractor.Start()     
print("...done")
```

I assume the problem is arising from my use of numpy arrays, so I have attempted to use vtkStructuredPoints but if I try to write a 1 to the vtkStrucutredPoints array I get the following error: TypeError: 'vtkobject' object is not subscriptable on the line `It[z][x][y] = 1` so I am not sure what that error message means.

The code I am using to create the vtkStructuredPoints array is

```
It = vtkStructuredPoints() 
It.SetDimensions(sizez, sizex, sizey) 
It.SetOrigin(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) 
It.SetSpacing(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
```

Thank you very much for any help or pointers you may be able to offer.

John